# Rotating a gaussian function - matlab

Tags: matlab, gaussian

Good day,

I have code that stretches and rotates a gaussian 2d pdf as such:

```
mu = [0 0];

Sigma = [1 0; 0 1];
Scale = [3 0; 0 1];
Theta = 10;
Rotate = [cosd(Theta) -sind(Theta); sind(Theta) cosd(Theta)];
Sigma = (Sigma*Scale)*Rotate

x1 = -100:1:100; x2 = -100:1:100;
[X1,X2] = meshgrid(x1,x2);
F = mvnpdf([X1(:) X2(:)],mu,Sigma);
F = reshape(F,length(x2),length(x1));

imshow(F*255)
```

Unfortunately, when I change Theta to a value other than 0, it says 
SIGMA must be a square, symmetric, positive definite matrix. Can I know what's going on

Comment: Are you sure you're rotating it correctly?  See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function#Two-dimensional_Gaussian_function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you consult the article on Wikipedia about the general elliptical version of the Gaussian 2D PDF, it doesn't look like you're rotating it properly.  In general, the equation is:

[image]

<sup>Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function#Two-dimensional_Gaussian_function)</sup>

where:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Usually, `A = 1` and we'll adopt that here.  The angle `theta` will rotate the PDF counter-clockwise, and so we can use this raw form of the equation over `mvnpdf`.  Using your definitions and constants, it would become this:

```
x1 = -100:1:100; x2 = -100:1:100;
[X1,X2] = meshgrid(X1, X2);
sigma1 = 1;
sigma2 = 1;
scale1 = 3;
scale2 = 1;
sigma1 = scale1*sigma1;
sigma2 = scale2*sigma2;
Theta = 10;

a = ((cosd(Theta)^2) / (2*sigma1^2)) + ((sind(Theta)^2) / (2*sigma2^2));
b = -((sind(2*Theta)) / (4*sigma1^2)) + ((sind(2*Theta)) / (4*sigma2^2));
c = ((sind(Theta)^2) / (2*sigma1^2)) + ((cosd(Theta)^2) / (2*sigma2^2));

mu = [0 0];
A = 1;
F = A*exp(-(a*(X1 - mu(1)).^2 + 2*b*(X1 - mu(1)).*(X2 - mu(2)) + c*(X2 - mu(2)).^2));
imshow(F*255);
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I should have consulted wikipedia first.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are trying to rotate the variances in 2D... You have to hit your sigma matrix with your transform on both sides of it since the "sigma" matrix is essentially a tensor.

```
mu = [0 0];

Sigma = [1 0; 0 1];
Scale = [10 0;0 1];
Theta = pi/3;
m = makehgtform('zrotate',Theta);
m = m(1:2,1:2);
Sigma = m*(Sigma*Scale)*m.';

x1 = -100:1:100; 
x2 = -100:1:100;
[X1,X2] = meshgrid(x1,x2);
F = mvnpdf([X1(:) X2(:)],mu,Sigma);
F = reshape(F,length(x2),length(x1));

imshow(F*255)
```